# Channels consumers garbage collector

Tags: django, garbage-collection, django-channels

What happens to a consumer instance after a websocket client disconnects? Is there any specific cleanup of the instance done, or just regular garbage collection?

Is it possible to reconnect to a channels consumer instance to recover the state of that instance?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to a consumer instance after a websocket client disconnects? Is there any specific cleanup of the instance done, or just regular garbage collection?

`def disconnect(self, code):` for websocket consumers should be called with the connection is closed. However this is not called if you have an exception or the connection times out.

If you want a higher chance of intercepting this you can overwrite the `async def __call__` method and wrap the `await super().__call__(...)` in try catch to capture any exceptions and act on them.

```py
async def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
   try:
      await super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
   finally:
      # do some very fast cleanup here
```

> Is it possible to reconnect to a channels consumer instance to recover the state of that instance?

No every connection gets a fresh intance. if you want to share state between them you can consider using:

- the users session (as long as it as a server side persitance)
- a db record
- Some other storage layer such as redis etc

Comment: Thank you very much!